# What does the lightning symbol mean?

Tags: papers-please

When you are at the your work station, there is a little box below the microphone and below the number. At times it flashes with a lightning symbol. I can't quite figure out what it means.

Comment: From what I see, the lightning symbol lights up when the entrant is speaking.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Arstotzka Ministry of Admission

Official bulletin

Inspector,

your booth has inspection hardware installed. The lightning symbol indicates that your conversation with the entrant is being recorded. Review the audio transcript to find discrepancies. The audio transcript is located behind the microphone.

[image: Inspector's Booth]

Refer [to the wikia](http://papersplease.wikia.com/wiki/Inspector's_Booth) for updated information on the features of your booth.
Internet use for recreational purposes at your workplace will result in a citation.

Follow all protocols strictly.

Glory to Arstotzka.